# How to define link text different in Odoo widget=url

Tags: odoo

I have made read only computed URL-field  based on invoice number. It works nicely but I would like to produce text part  only itself like 400:

```
<a href="https://external_site_invoice?num=400">400</a>
```

Now it's producing whole link as text which is quite ugly

```
<a href="https://external_site_invoice?num=400">https://external_site_invoice?num=400</a>
```

My Odoo fields are defined this way...

```
ext_invoice_number= fields.Integer(string="Ext number")

def _showlink(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.ext_invoice_number:
            if  rec.ext_invoice_number>0:
                rec.ext_link="https://external site/invoice?num=%d" % (rec.ext_invoice_number,)


ext_link = fields.Char(string="Link",compute=_showlink,)
```

How can I define text part of URL in Odoo to be different than link? This is poorly documented or it's not possible?

Answer (score 9):

you can define the **text** attribute in widget definition like that:

```
<field name="field_with_url" widget="url" readonly="1" text="My own text"/>
```

Regards

Comment: saved me hours trying to find this solution